# Type inference for lambda parameter types

Tags: kotlin, type-inference

Kotlin fails to compile this code because, as the compiler states "Error: Smart cast to 'Nothing' is impossible, because 'accumulator' is a complex expression"

Ye olde function is called what you'd expect, i.e., I want to return the indexOfMax -- but what's more important is understanding why the "smart cast" failed to cast to `accumulator` an `Int`

```
fun indexOfMax(a: IntArray): Int? {
    return a.foldIndexed(null) { index, accumulator, element ->
        return if (accumulator is Int) {
            var i:Int = accumulator
            return if (accumulator == null) index
                   else if (element > a[i]) index
                   else accumulator
        } else accumulator
    }
}
```

## edit

yes, the accepted answer works! Here's the solution:

```
fun indexOfMax(a: IntArray): Int? {
    return a.foldIndexed(null as Int?) { index, accumulator, element ->
        if (accumulator == null) index
            else if (element >= a[accumulator]) index
            else accumulator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `accumulator` here is inferred only from the initial value argument, which is `null`. That `null` has type `Nothing?`. After checking that the type of `accumulator` is `Int`, you get its type smartcasted to the intersection of `Nothing?` and `Int`, which results in `Nothing`.

The solution here is to specify either the function type parameters explicitly, or to specify the type of the argument:

```
a.foldIndexed(null as Int?) { ...
// or
a.foldIndexed<Int?>(null) { ...
```

Comment: Interesting, how is it that you found "smart casts" are determined by the intersection of the types?